# How to return a partial JSON response using python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, filter, whitelist

I have a json (or a python dictionary) and I would like to define a whitelist of fields.

```
{
    "firstname": "user",
    "last_name":"test",
    "roles": ["admin", "country"], 
    "languages":{"first":"english", "second":"french"}
}
```

Specifying firstname, roles languages and first should output:

```
{
    "firstname": "user",
    "roles": ["admin", "country"],
    "languages":{"first":"english"}
}
```

its easy to do for first level, but how can I do it for second, third level etc...

Comment: You mean you want a 'template' of sorts to add to?

Comment: some kind of template yes

Comment: first level, I mean flat json, non multidimentional

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make a recursive function that checks the type of each dictionary element and their white list membership. If type of element N is a dictionary, call again to function incrementing some level counter.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it for "first level", apply recursion to do it for "second, third, level, etc".

```
def dict_filter(d, keep):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return { k:dict_filter(v, keep) for k,v in d.iteritems() if k in keep }
    return d


orig = {
    "firstname": "user",
    "last_name":"test",
    "roles": ["admin", "country"],
    "languages":{"first":"english", "second":"french"}
}

keepers = ['firstname', 'roles', 'languages', 'first']
print dict_filter(orig, keepers)
```